# EF Core many to many relationship - update join table / update related data without join class

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core

I am new in C# and .net and basically trying to follow tutorials with minor changes.
I have following two classes and a many to many relationship between them. The join table was automatically created by EF Core. The code below is trimmed to essentials.

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public List<Pictogram> Pictograms { get; } = new();
}
```

and

```
public class Pictogram
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string PictogramName { get; set; }
    public string PictogramNumber { get; set; }
    public string PictogramUrl { get; set; }
    public List<Item> Items{ get; } = new();
}
```

As mentioned, I am following the tutorial [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/update-related-data?view=aspnetcore-8.0](https://stackoverflow.com) while updating scaffolded controller and changing the code so that it fits to my classes and not completely copying the tutorial.

Unfortunately, the tutorial describes 3rd class for join table in order to work with the many to many relationships, including handling the Edit action.

In my case, each Item has several pictograms and they appear in Edit view with corresponding checkboxes.

As for now I have a following code for Edit action.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("Id,ItemName")] Item item, string[] selectedPictograms)
{
    if (id != item.Id)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var itemToUpdate = await _context.Items
                                     .Include(i => i.Pictograms)
                                     .AsNoTracking()
                                     .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        UpdateItemPictograms(selectedPictograms, itemToUpdate);

        try
        {
            _context.Update(item);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!ItemExists(item.Id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }

    UpdateItemlPictograms(selectedPictograms, itemToUpdate);
    PopulateAssignedPictogramData(itemToUpdate);

    return View(item);
}

private void UpdateItemlPictograms(string[] selectedPictograms, Item itemToUpdate)
{
    if (selectedPictograms == null) 
    {
        return; 
    }

    var selectedPictogramsHS = new HashSet<string>(selectedPictograms);
    var itemPictograms = new HashSet<int>(itemToUpdate.Pictograms.Select(i => i.Id));
    var item = itemToUpdate;

    foreach(var pictogram in _context.Pictograms)
    {
        if (selectedPictogramsHS.Contains(pictogram.Id.ToString()))
        {
            // TODO Problem here
            item.Pictograms.Add(pictogram);
        }
    }
}
```

Up until last lines the code seems to work fine. I can actually create and edit items if I do not try to assign pictograms to them.

`var selectedPictogramsHS` has the `Id` values of the pictograms that I want to assign.

`var itemPictograms` does contain the already assigned pictograms (manual entry in the join table in the database).

`var item` is the right item that I am trying to edit.

At this point I am stack. This code does nothing. And the tutorial, as well as several online search results, describe the situation where I should work with additional class for join table, such as:

```
itemToUpdate.ItemPictograms.Add(new ItemPictogram { ItemId = itemToUpdate.Id, PictogramId = pictogram.PictogramId });
```

As mentioned, I do not have a class for joint table in my models. I must be some tricky way for directly updating the joint table that I just cant find and do not know yet.

Any help or hint will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there will be any issue with the relationship, but there are several serious issues with the approach you are using.

Firstly, the best way to update entities and especially those with related entities is to utilize EF's change tracking. It is one of the main reasons to use an ORM like EF. This means *not* using `DbSet.Update()`:

```
var itemToUpdate = await _context.Items
    .Include(i => i.Pictograms)
    .SingleAsync(m => m.Id == id);
```

This loads the desired item and its pictogram collection which we can modify. If there are properties on the passed in item data to update we can use the setters on the itemToUpdate to update the relevant values. The next step will be to update the pictogram references. The first step is if the pictogram Ids are passed in as `string` but are ints:

```
var updatedPictogramIds = selectedPictograms.Select(x => int.Parse(x))
    .ToList();
```

Next will be to determine which pictograms need to be added and which need to be removed:

```
var existingPictogramIds = itemToUpdate.Pictograms
    .Select(p => p.Id)
    .ToList();
var pictogramIdsToAdd = updatedPictogramIds.Except(existingPictogramIds);
var pictogramIdsToRemove = existingPictogramIds.Except(updatedPictogramIds);

if (pictogramIdsToRemove.Any())
{
    var pictogramsToRemove = itemToUpdate.Pictograms
        .Where(p => pictogramIdsToRemove.Contains(p.Id))
        .ToList();
    foreach(var pictogram in pictogramsToRemove)
        itemToUpdate.Pictograms.Remove(pictogram);
}
if (pictogramIdsToAdd.Any())
{
    var pictogramsToAdd = await _context.Pictograms
        .Where(p => pictogramIdsToAdd.Contains(p.Id))
        .ToListAsync();
    foreach(var pictogram in pictogramsToAdd)
        itemToUpdate.Pictograms.Add(pictogram);
}

await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

This compares the Ids of the pictograms you currently have with the updated set to determine which need to be removed and which need to be added. For the Ids to remove we find those in the item and remove them which will de-associate them from the item. For the Ids to be added we load the references from the DbContext and add them to the item. Once this is done, we just need to call `SaveChanges` and the change tracker does the rest.